# How to override an argument passed with "..."

Tags: r, plot

Say I write the following function

```
f = function(x, y, ...){
    plot(x, ...)
    lines(y, col='red', ...)
}
```

This throws an error when I call `f` with the argument `col=`. I know how to find what arguments are passed with `...`, but I would like to remove `col` from them if it is there, so the following works. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set that value it would be easiest to just intercept that one as well to prevent it from going into the `...` in the first place.

```
f = function(x,y,col='red',...){
 plot(x,...)
 lines(y,col=col,...)
}
```

Or you can do grab the dots and adjust them, but then you have to pass along arguments as we list via do.call

```
f = function(x,y,...){
 plot(x,...)
 dots <-list(...)
 dots$col<-NULL
 do.call(lines, c(list(y,col="red"), dots))
}
```